# Flutter error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: json, flutter, response

Hope you can help me, i'm doing an app where i get data the data from another url post of a person like this json body:

```
{
   "orderId":null,
   "orderNumber":null,
   "orderCode":"VE",
   "branchCode":"1214001",
   "companyNumber":null,
   "currency":"MXN",
   "exchangeRate":0.0,
   "creationDate":"2023-03-21T21:42:52.915+00:00",
   "requestDate":"2023-03-21T21:42:52.915+00:00",
   "validityDate":"2023-03-21T21:42:52.915+00:00",
   "client":{
      "id":1,
      "noClient":1,
      "taxpayer":"M",
      "customerType":"",
      "rfc":"XAXX010101010",
      "name":"GENERIC",
      "fatherSurname":"GENERIC",
      "motherSurname":"GENERIC",
      "businessName":"CLIENTE UNIVERSAL",
      "contact":".",
      "phone":"0000000000",
      "cell":"0000000000",
      "howToContact":"",
      "workType":"",
      "iva":"16",
      "taxRegime":"RPN",
      "mail":null,
      "nnn001":" - ",
      "direction":null,
      "shippingAddress":null,
      "enabled":false,
      "shippingAddressList":null,
      "mailList":null
   },
   "clientTax":16.0,
   "clientReference":"",
   "userNumber":null,
   "idUser":null,
   "employeeEmail":"DANIEL@EXAMPLE.COM.MX",
   "subTotal":2038.78,
   "ivaTotal":326.2,
   "orderTotal":2364.98,
   "pendingPayment":2364.98,
   "discountTotal":0.0,
   "addresses":[
      {
         "id":null,
         "street":"MEX",
         "colony":"COLONIA",
         "state":"NUEVO LEON NLE",
         "stateCode":"019",
         "delegation":"SALINAS VICTORIA ",
         "delegationCode":"019045",
         "interiorNumber":"00",
         "outdoorNumber":"00",
         "cp":"65536",
         "city":"MEXICO",
         "addressType":"Fiscal",
         "flat":"PLANO 019 CIUDAD DE MEXICO",
         "flatCode":"019",
         "coordinate":"1D",
         "coordinateCode":"1D"
      },
      {
         "id":null,
         "street":"CALLE",
         "colony":"COLONIA",
         "state":"NUEVO LEON NLE",
         "stateCode":"019",
         "delegation":"SALINAS VICTORIA ",
         "delegationCode":"019045",
         "interiorNumber":"00",
         "outdoorNumber":"00",
         "cp":"65536",
         "city":"MEXICO",
         "addressType":"Envío",
         "flat":"PLANO 019 CIUDAD DE MEXICO",
         "flatCode":"019",
         "coordinate":"1E",
         "coordinateCode":"1E"
      }
   ]
}
```

then i need to use the only the address body info to send it to another url, but when i do it, it shows me this error

[error_message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZiED.png)

and i know its the way i call it because i have try other things but nothing works.

I have try like this:

```
{
          "id": dataClient['direction']['id'],
          "street": "${dataClient['direction']['street']}",
          "colony": "${dataClient['direction']['colony']}",
          "state": "${estadoCliente}",
          "stateCode": "${dataClient['direction']['stateCode']}",
          "delegation": "${mudegCliente}",
          "delegationCode": "${dataClient['direction']['delegationCode']}",
          "interiorNumber": "${dataClient['direction']['noInterior']}",
          "outdoorNumber": "${dataClient['direction']['noOutdoor']}",
          "cp": "${dataClient['direction']['cp']}",
          "city": "${dataClient['direction']['city']}",
          "addressType": "Fiscal",
          "flat": "${fatCliente}",
          "flatCode": "${dataClient['direction']['flatCode']}",
          "coordinate": "${coordCliente}",
          "coordinateCode": "${dataClient['direction']['coordinatesCode']}"
        },
        {
          "id": dataClient['shippingAddressList'][0]['id'],
          "street": "${dataClient['shippingAddressList'][0]['street']}",
          "colony": "${dataClient['shippingAddressList'][0]['colony']}",
          "state": "${estadoClienteSend}",
          "stateCode": "${dataClient['shippingAddressList'][0]['stateCode']}",
          "delegation": "${mudegClienteSend}",
          "delegationCode":
              "${dataClient['shippingAddressList'][0]['delegationCode']}",
          "interiorNumber":
              "${dataClient['shippingAddressList'][0]['noInterior']}",
          "outdoorNumber":
              "${dataClient['shippingAddressList'][0]['noOutdoor']}",
          "cp": "${dataClient['shippingAddressList'][0]['cp']}",
          "city": "${dataClient['shippingAddressList'][0]['city']}",
          "addressType": "Envío",
          "flat": "${fatClienteSend}",
          "flatCode": "${dataClient['shippingAddressList'][0]['flatCode']}",
          "coordinate": "${coordClienteSend}",
          "coordinateCode":
              "${dataClient['shippingAddressList'][0]['coordinatesCode']}"
        }
```

and also tried putting the information on a list dynamic but also the same:

```
List adresses;

adresses =
          jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))['data']['addresses'];
```

Only when Static Info on the data to send it it´s how it works well. Hope you guys canl help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appears when you pass a String where Flutter is expecting a type int. e.g. If Flutter is expecting List[0] and you pass List['value'].

Try doing the same operation with smaller data, with fewer lines. This will allow you to pinpoint where you are going wrong.

Cheers!